# Keep variables between scenes with DontDestroyOnLoad not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to keep some variables when changing an scene (lives and gems).

With `DontDestroyOnLoad`, the object doesn't destroy, but the variables do, and reset to 5 lives and 0 gems.

Here is my code

**GameControlle**

```
void Start ()
{
    GameObject keeper = GameObject.Find ("VARKEEPER");
    varkeeper = keeper.GetComponent<KeepVars> ();
}

void Update ()
{
    LiveChecker();
}

void LiveChecker()
{
    if (lives == 5) {
        lives1.enabled = true;
        lives2.enabled = true;
        lives3.enabled = true;
        lives4.enabled = true;
        lives5.enabled = true;
    } else if (lives == 4) {
        lives1.enabled = true;
        lives2.enabled = true;
        lives3.enabled = true;
        lives4.enabled = true;
        lives5.enabled = false;
    } else if (lives == 3) {
        lives1.enabled = true;
        lives2.enabled = true;
        lives3.enabled = true;
        lives4.enabled = false;
        lives5.enabled = false;
    } else if (lives == 2) {
        lives1.enabled = true;
        lives2.enabled = true;
        lives3.enabled = false;
        lives4.enabled = false;
        lives5.enabled = false;
    } else if (lives == 1) {
        lives1.enabled = true;
        lives2.enabled = false;
        lives3.enabled = false;
        lives4.enabled = false;
        lives5.enabled = false;
    } else if (lives <= 0) {
        lives1.enabled = false;
        lives2.enabled = false;
        lives3.enabled = false;
        lives4.enabled = false;
        lives5.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

**VarKeeper**

```
public int lives;
public int gems;

GameControlle gameController;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake ()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad (this);
}

void Start () 
{
    GameObject player = GameObject.Find ("Character");
    gameController = player.GetComponent<GameControlle> ();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    lives = gameController.lives;

    gems = gameController.gems;
}
```

The system I am using to get the vars may not be the proper one..

Comment: Where do you set the values (the 5 and the 0)? I suspect that `lives = gameController.lives` (and the one for gems) set them back to that and this is actually not a problem with the `DontDestroyOnLoad`.

Comment: On a sidenote: I suggest to change your system of updating your lives. Don't do all these if statements. Fire some update when you actually change the lives.

Comment: Or at least not each `Update()` is what I mean.

Comment: The initial values are set at the beginning. I declare the variables and set them (public int lives = 5)

What do you suggest for the live system?

@GunnarB

Comment: Is the object your `VarKeeper` is on actually a child of some other object? In that case `DontDestroyOnLoad` will not work since it doesn't effect parents.

Comment: No it's not @GunnarB

Comment: For the lives: At some point you change the value (e.g. because the object got hit by something). At this point you would also do some call to change the sprites(?) etc. Also, you have your varkeeper, but actually the gamecontroller holds the values, at least you refer to some member in your lifechecker, not to `varkeeper.lives`.

Comment: Is GameController on the same game object as VarKeeper? if not, then VarKeeper survives but GameController is destroyed and maybe recreated in the next scene. So it sets the value again.

Comment: The varkeeper is in its own gameobject, an empty one. Should I attach it to the player? (Where the gamecontroller is) @Everts

Comment: But I do want the player gameobject to be destroyed when changing the scene

Comment: There are things in your VarKeeper that are doomed. If you are not keeping the GameController, I assume you get a new one in the next scene. Though your VarKeeper still refers to the old one. Running in the update it could break any time. It would be better to inform the VarKeeper from the GameController when gems or lives are affected. You would save performances. If you get a new GameController, since you get the values in Update, I guess it gets the new value from the new GC.

Comment: Actually, I think I've found the problem. I've changed my scripts so that everything related to gems and lives is stored on VarKeeper. My question is, where should I put the VarKeeper object? I want the player to come back to the same scene, but when the scene is loaded the second time, there are 2 varkeepers. I think that is the main problem @Everts

Answer (score 0):

Okay just solved it.

Basically what I did is to make VarKeeper control all the variables (gems and lives). I changed at GameController everything that included `lives` to `varkeeper.lives`, and the same with gems.

Basically that solved it